Deploying an angular site to an Azure-StaticWebApp gives error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
When I check in my changes, the automatic deploy starts. However, every time I get the following error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
Upon checking the logs I found this:

The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest
Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid.

I have no idea what the problem is.
This is my yml:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-kind-grass-0dc0dff03-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_KIND_GRASS_0DC0DFF03)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "dist/musicandbooksapplication.client" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

This should be the repository:
https://dev.azure.com/BartSchelkens0964/MusicApplication/_git/MusicAndBooksApplication?version=GBmaster&_a=contents
Can anyone help me?

If possible, share your GitHub repository?

I will not have access to your private repository (Devops Repository). Provide me public repository (Git Hub)

@AsleshaKantamsetti It should be public now.

I will try on my side and let you know.

Your app_location should be musicandbookapplication.client.


The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid.

The issue is with invalid Azure_Static_Web_App_Api_Token.
To resolve the issue, I copied the Manage deployment token from Azure Static web app.
Go to Overview -> Manage deployment token -> Deployment token.

I added the above copied token value to the Variables section.
Go to Pipelines Symbol -> Library -> Variables -> AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_SAND_0083CEA10 -> value as shown below.

Updated the app location and output location.
 app_location: "/musicandbooksapplication.client"
 output_location: "dist/musicandbooksapplication.client/browser"

Below is my complete devops yml file.
azure-static-web-apps-polite-sand-0083cea10.yml:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-polite-sand-0083cea10-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_SAND_0083CEA10)
      app_location: "/musicandbooksapplication.client"
      api_location: "" 
      output_location: "dist/musicandbooksapplication.client/browser" 

Azure Static Web App Output:


@alesha kantamsetti: I tried it and I get the following error: "deployment_token provided was invalid.
An unknown exception has occurred
"

@Bart Schelkens If you are still facing issue, create new Azure Static web app and redeploy it.

@Bart Schelkens What is your yml file name?

it seems I have 2:

azure-static-web-apps-kind-grass-0dc0dff03.yml
azure-static-web-apps-ashy-bay-0291ae503.yml


@Bart Schelkens Make sure Copy and paste the Correct deployment token.

It seems my pipeline is now working, but I'm not seeing my site.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
